# R studio on Mac, how to knit to pdf?

Tags: r, macos, latex

I have some trouble with the knit function on R studio. It looks like it's finished with the "100%"?
but then an error message shows as the below, and asks me to install Latex. I followed the guideline and just successfully installed MacTex. However the same message showed up again.
I was wondering probably I missed some steps? cause I didn't do anything else after installing, should I connect it with r studio/loading it like a library? 
thank you!

```
! sh: pdflatex: command not found

Error: LaTeX failed to compile 6501-hw1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See 6501-hw1.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  error in running command
Execution halted

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()

  Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

  MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

  Linux: Use system package manager
```

[enter image description here][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnBaf.png

Comment: If you don't have reasons otherwise, use `TinyTeX`. It is now recommended for `rmarkdown`.

Comment: which platform/OS are you using? try running `installr::install.MikTeX()` first to be able to install Latex, then you could knit the markdown to pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you try running "tinytex::install_tinytex()", close RStudio, re-open it and knit should work.